# Re-render Nativescript ListView when ObservableArray item changes

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

This is how I render the `cases` ObservableArray in my view

```
<ListView [items]="cases" class="list-group" *ngIf="cases">
    <ng-template let-case="item">
```

Say `cases` has these values:

`cases = [{id: 1, name: "Sam"}, {id: 2, name: "Romio"}]`

How can I get my ListView to re-render or somehow update the view when I update the first item like this?

`cases[0]["name"] = "Michael"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to do apply the change in [NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)? I used this to update an array (not ObservableArray) and the corresponding RadListView automatically was updating.

```
this.ngZone.run(() => {

        this.dummyService.addFile(this.file).subscribe(
            (fileId) => {
                this.folder.push(this.file);
        },
        (error) => {
           this handleError(error);
        });
     });
```

Comment: Yesss!! This is the answer, thank you. It works as I want it and with ListView. Although I don't get it why ngZone did the magic!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to enforce immutability here. So if you must mutate the first object in the array I would. I would try using the spread operator afterward.

```
cases[0]["name"] = "Michael"
cases = [...cases];
```

this will set `cases` to a new instance of an array which should update the list.

Comment: I already tried changing the instance but nativescript doesn't re-render the view when you do that until you hit something in the UI. Any action you do is sufficient to re-render. But just changing the instance itself is not enough. Instead of update, I also tried to keep the same instance, and remove the old object and add the new object to the array but with no success. Nothing is re-rendering the view until you do some action to the UI!